# LSTM occurs ValueError: Shapes (5, 2, 3) and (5, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I want to do time series multi-class classification with time-series data. Here the data set I have got needs to be preprocessed heavily and that just to get an idea of how to implement the model I have used the IRIS data set(not suitable for LSTM) since it has the exact same structure of the time series data I have( 4 input features,1 output feature, 120 samples). I have the following code implemented but it causes me the invalid shape error when fitting the model with a batch size of 5 (changed the batch size many times but didn't seem to make any change)

```
#load dataset
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv",header=None)
    dataset = dataframe.values
    X=dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
    Y=dataset[:,4]
```

```
# Encode the output variables
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(Y)
    # convert output variables into the numbers
    encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
    # Convert integers to dummy variables (one-hot encoded)
    dummy_Y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,dummy_Y,test_size=0.2) #20% is allocated for the testing
```

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(60, 2, 4)
y_train = y_train.reshape(60, 2, 3)
y_train.shape,X_train.shape
```

> ((60, 2, 3), (60, 2, 4))

```
 # Create the Neural Network Model
def create_nn_model():
#create sequential model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

```
model = create_nn_model()
model.summary()
```

```
> Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               42000     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 303       
=================================================================
Total params: 52,403
Trainable params: 52,403
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=200,batch_size=5)
```

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-26-0aef33c299f0> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=200,batch_size=5) #X_train is independant variables. based on the amount of the data set data set will be trained by breaking into batches

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:830 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:813 run_step  *
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:771 train_step  *
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__  *
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:142 __call__  *
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:246 call  *
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:1631 categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:4827 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (5, 2, 3) and (5, 3) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y_true` and `y_pred` are not in the same shape. You may need to define your LSTM in the following way

```
model.add(LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, input_shape=(2,4), return_sequences=True))
....
```

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
....
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2, 3)              303        < ---
=================================================================
```

### Update

Using `return_sequences = True` would work because you define your Training-Paris in that way:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(60, 2, 4)
y_train = y_train.reshape(60, 2, 3)
```

which represent `(batch_size, timestep, input_lenght)`; but note that you need to reshape or fulfill the input requirement of the LSTM layer in your above model and not the `y_train`. However, when you define your model, you don't use the return sequence and it makes the last layer have only the three classifiers without timestep, but your `y_train` is defined in that way. But if you set the return sequence to True and plot your model summary, you would see that the last layer will have an output shape of (`None, 2, 3`) which exactly matches the shape of  `y_train`.

Before understanding what the `return_sequence` is doing here, you may need to know what timestep means in an LSTM Model, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236050/9215780) answer. AFAIK, it depends on how many timesteps you need to set for your input; I can make a single occurrence of the LSTM cell or multiple times (`n-th` timestep). And for `n-th` timestep (`n: {1,2,3..N`), if I want from LSTM to return all timestep output (`n` numbers), then I will set `return_sequence = True`, but else `return_sequence = False`. From [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/),

> **return_sequences**: Boolean. Whether to return the last output. in the output sequence, or the full sequence. Default: False.

In short, if it sets as True, all sequences will return but if it's False, then only the last output will. For example:

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 8])
inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, 2, 4 ]) # or [-1, 4, 2] # or [-1, 1, 8]
inputs.shape 
TensorShape([32, 2, 4]) # (batch_size, timestep, input_length)

lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)
whole_seq_output = lstm(inputs)
print(whole_seq_output.shape)
(32, 2, 10) # (batch_size, timestep, output_length)

lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=False)
last_seq_output = lstm(inputs)
print(last_seq_output.shape)
(32, 10) # (batch_size, output_length)
```

---

Here is a one-way approach to your above code. Iris data took from [here](https://gist.github.com/netj/8836201#file-iris-csv).

```
import pandas 
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("/content/iris.csv")
dataframe.head(3)

  sepal.length  sepal.width petal.length    petal.width   variety
0   5.1              3.5         1.4             0.2      Setosa
1   4.9              3.0         1.4             0.2      Setosa
2   4.7              3.2         1.3             0.2      Setosa
```

```
dataframe.variety.unique()
array(['Setosa', 'Versicolor', 'Virginica'], dtype=object)
```

```
target_map = dict(zip(list(dataframe['variety'].unique()), 
                     ([0, 1, 2])))
target_map
{'Setosa': 0, 'Versicolor': 1, 'Virginica': 2}
```

```
dataframe['target'] = dataframe.variety.map(target_map) 
dataframe.sample()
    sepal.length    sepal.width petal.length  petal.width   variety   target
128      6.4             2.8       5.6           2.1       Virginica    2
```

```
X = dataframe.iloc[:, :4] 
Y = dataframe.iloc[:, 5]

X.shape, Y.shape
((150, 4), (150,))
```

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

OHE_Y = to_categorical(Y, num_classes=3)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, OHE_Y, 
                                                      test_size=0.2)

X_train.shape
(120, 4)

# make it lstm compatible input 
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1, 4)

X_train.shape ,y_train.shape
((120, 1, 4), (120, 3))
```

**Model**

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense 

def create_nn_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],
                                               X_train.shape[2])))
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = create_nn_model()
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,batch_size=5)

...
Epoch 9/10
3ms/step - loss: 0.5224 - accuracy: 0.7243
Epoch 10/10
3ms/step - loss: 0.5568 - accuracy: 0.7833
```

**Inference**

```
model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
4ms/step - loss: 0.3843 - accuracy: 0.9583
[0.38432881236076355, 0.9583333134651184]

y_pred = model.predict(X_train).argmax(-1)
y_pred
array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0,
       0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0,
       2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0,
       0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
       0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: Yes setting return_sequences to true has worked but i don't understand why do i need to return a sequence here. And when that done and finally predict the class whether it is Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor , Iris-virginica . But the output i get is a little unclear as it returns a sequence of values

Comment: And will you please be able to mention that how to decide the time steps that the input data to the network should have

Comment: Can you elaborate, three inputs and one output...?

Comment: I do have a question though. can i predict a one possible class considering three samples all together like                                                        model.predict([[[6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5]],[[6.3, 2.76, 4.4, 1.3]],[[5.5, 3.8, 1.6, 0.5]]]).argmax(-1). But this gets me an output of three possible classes like array([1, 1, 0]). Assuming this is time series telemetry data coming from a device with a interval of 1 sec. there will be 3 records came within 3 sec to check if it faulty or normal

Comment: So i will have to input all these three time series samples to get an output whether it is faulty or normal and even to diagnose the which fault (which label). I'm just checking on doing a fault detection and diagnosis with LSTM. Or is LSTM not suitable for the scenario I'm describing?

Comment: model.predict([[[6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5],[5.5, 3.8, 1.6, 0.5],[5.5, 3.8, 1.6, 0.5]]]).argmax(-1) this got me a one possible class label. But the shape of this input I'm passing is (1, 2, 4) which has 2 time steps. Another question is why can't we use 2 time steps in input data for the LSTM layer? if there is only one time step then there will be no recurrence of the same cell right?

Comment: Not sure if I follow you properly. When you set (1, 2, 4) = (batch_size, time_step, input_lenght) - by this you use 2 time step. If there is only a one-time step e.g (1, 1, 8), there will be no recurrence of the same cell.

Comment: Exactly. What I'm not clear is based on what do we decide how many time steps i should define when shaping the input to the LSTM layer. If i set it up for 2 time steps like in (60,2,4) for X_train instead of (120,1,4) I have to return sequences as the output of the layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234079/discussion-between-sinfer-and-m-innat).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and your time ;) would like to know a little bit more on here about the way deciding the number of time steps

Comment: Regarding the choosing time-step, can you check [this](https://qr.ae/pGHibs). And about the problem description, I think you can consider this as a multi-input and single output model approach; where input would be 3 samples and output would be whether it's faulty or normal. I wish I can help more. Please kindly ask a new question if you still have a query.

Comment: Sure i will check the link. Followed your upper code and it was great and worked with single time step now i want to explore more like what happens with multiple time steps. I think should go to a new question. Thanks a lot for your effort time and patience ;)